# Adding Guest Wireless/Wired Network on Separate Subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I currently have a 300Mbps wireless router (TP Link WR841N v9) hooked up to a cable modem. This provides internet access for my home network (tablets, desktop, laptops, printer, etc.).

I want to set up a guest network for a different part of my house which would be unable to access the home network (isolated from the home network). From what I understand, here are my best options:

1. Cascading a second router from my main router via an ethernet cable (LAN port on main router to WAN on secondary router) with DHCP on
2. Set up second router in repeater mode with DHCP on (wireless communication between main router and secondary router)
3. Get a non-wireless router connected to the cable modem then have both the main router and secondary router connect to that (triple Y-config). That requires getting a non-wireless router and second router though, so is less preferable in terms of $.

Can someone confirm that these options will provide a secondary wireless network that will not be able to access data/traffic/devices from the home network?

The downside to option 1 is that because the secondary network will be for a different part of my house (cannot run ethernet cable there) devices in that area would have to be run off of wireless, instead of having the option to be hardwired. Because of this I think I prefer option 2, but have a few questions.

I understand option 2 will reduce the throughput by 50%. Will this reduction in bandwidth be felt on the secondary router (repeater) only? Also, does the bandwidth reduction refer to the router speed or internet speed (if I use a 300Mbps router with a 75Mbps downstream cable internet connection, would I notice a degradation of internet speed?)

Also, for option 2, would someone definitely be able to connect to the repeater router via a hardwired connection or a wireless connection?

Thanks.

Comment: This question will almost definitely have a number of opinion-based responses. However, you could invest in a router that can provide VLAN support. An example is a DrayTek Vigor 2920n - this version is dual-WAN but I've used one in the past for a dual-WAN customer. The VLAN capabilities allowed us to have separate wireless networks completely isolated from one another. Alternatively you could get a router that can be flashed to, say, Tomato...

Comment: While I appreciate the added capability of a $200+ router like the one you mentioned, I'm not really looking to spend that much.  Additionally, I'd prefer to have the option to hardwire devices in that separate portion of my home where the guest network would be.  Only the repeater option (#2) would provide that ability, as far as I know, given that I cannot run an ethernet cable to that portion of my home.